# spree install at openshift with ruby on rails. i am unable to install it

Tags: openshift, spree

I installed spree on my local machine with ruby on rail in windows. but i am unable to install spree on openshift server . there is an option on openshift to install spree but when i add application it give me error .

You can manage your new MySQL database by also embedding phpmyadmin. The phpmyadmin username and password will be the same as the MySQL credentials above.
The initial build for the application failed: Shell command '/sbin/runuser -s /bin/sh 543b667de0b8cd99e0000afa -c "exec /usr/bin/runcon 'unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c4,c669' /bin/sh -c \"gear postreceive --init >> /tmp/initial-build.log 2>&1\""' returned an error. rc=255 .Last 10 kB of build output: Stopping MySQL 5.1 cartridge Stopping Ruby cartridge Repairing links for 1 deployments Building git ref 'master', commit 99e1319 Building Ruby cartridge bundle install --deployment --path ./app-root/repo/vendor/bundle NOTE: You can prevent installing certain Gemfile group using: rhc env set BUNDLE_WITHOUT=groupname You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the updated Gemfile.lock to version control. You have added to the Gemfile: * source: https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git (at 2-2-stable) * source: https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git (at 2-2-stable) * rails (~> 4.0.5) * rack (~> 1.5.2) * pg * thor (= 0.18.1) * sass-rails * coffee-rails * execjs * libv8 * therubyracer * rmagick * spree (= 2.2.2) You have deleted from the Gemfile: * source: git://github.com/spree/spree.git (at 2-0-stable) * source: git://github.com/spree/spree_fancy.git (at 2-0-stable) * source:  (at 2-0-stable) * source:(at 2-0-stable) * coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1) * rack (~> 1.4.5) * rails (~> 3.2.13) * sass-rails (~> 3.2.3) * spree * spree_fancy * turbo-sprockets-rails3 You have changed in the Gemfile: * spree_gateway from `https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git (at 2-2-stable)` to `no specified source` * spree_auth_devise from `https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git (at 2-2-stable)` to `no specified source` An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 16) Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build' for /var/lib/openshift/543b667de0b8cd99e0000afa/ruby For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.

Answer (score 1):

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1018483

this is a known limitation that quickstarts that take longer than 4 mins to install are not compatible with --from-code